# Overwriting a file with another file Java/processing

Tags: java, file, processing, overwrite

Maybe it's just me that stupid, but i can't get this to work in, only if i try it in a file where i haven't writen anything but this:

```
boolean runOnce = true;

  File temp = new File("myPath/tempX.txt");
  File test = new File("myPath/xCordLayout.txt");

  if (runOnce) {
    if (test.delete()) {
      System.out.println("Success");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Failed");
    }
    runOnce = false;
  }

  if (temp.renameTo(test)) {
    System.out.println("File has been renamed!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
  }
```

The program syestem.out.println says Failed, so its the deleting part that doesn't seem to work.

if i have it in the same way, but you have to press a buttom or somethinh else, i doesn't seem to work ( i have tested the other statements, to check if there is something wrong with them but idk). Can someone help me, or tell me how to overwrite another file?

Comment: Your problem description is very poor, also you code is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so: what are the exact preconditions? Does the file to delete exist?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can actually run.

Comment: Does the file `myPath/xCordLayout.txt` really exist ? If not, it is normal that you cannot delete it. The constructor of File class doesn't create files.